# combining photogrammetry and a model in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, photogrammetry

Where to start, i've run out of googling for the answers. I Scanned a dolls house, with the intention of recreating it perfectly. However, the scan has a few holes in the mesh, and has about 3 million points. So, i decided to build the house from scratch using the photogrammetry model as my template. The original scan gives me the image textures, all placed perfectly in blender. Will i be able to use the "reshaper" PNG texture on my model? ( or is the texture info specifically built in to the original scan info? and wont work on a new build?). I have searched to see if anyone has combined a photogrammetry model with a built model, but i cant find what i need. There are some parts of the model that are beautiful , the detailed tiles on the roof ( as an example) but its made from a mess of polygons. I think i am perhaps asking for something that's not possible - to join a messy mesh and my model together to make something perfect, without holes. Before i loose the will to live, i downloaded Zbrush and decimated the model , but, although that worked well, i am unsure how that will benefit me, but still at least it worked, which is more than can be said for my efforts of combining the two models. I've been blending for about a month and made a doughnut.. a small victory.  Also, if anyone has any pointers to the best way of cutting arches into walls ( without using Boolean that i fear will rip up my walls) i'd appreciate a point to any tutorials. ( i've watched a few , but as yet i am am unwilling to accept that its as faffy as it ever was when i tried Blender 10 years ago )

Comment: thank you rjg. Is there a limit to the size of the mesh one can put into blender- the photoscanned one , i've got it down from 1,216,304kb to 19,370 ( using zbrush) after watching a Gleb tutorial about decimation. However, although zbrush decimated it nicely,  I think Blender does as good a job of decimating as zbrush -has. When Gleb said zbrush was the best at decimation , it was 2016.

Comment: It depends on your hardware. If your model is ~20 MB large it should work well.

Comment: Does the mesh and the model have to be exact , or near enough? Thank you for  your replies, appreciate it.

Comment: Close enough usually works fine. Of course textures can't compensate for large differences in the geometry, so you want to get the overall shape to match.